# Two column div, 100% width?

Tags: css

I have a series of buttons on my website that have I want to be at 100% width with a fixed column on the right and a flexible one on the left.

My first thought on how to do this was to use a liquid page layout and just use it on a div instead of the whole page. My results are below:

This image is what happens when the page is displayed so that the link can fit within the box.

[image: One]

If the page is scaled down however, I want the right column (set at `70px`) to fill the entire height and align the text horizontally.

[image: Two]

The code I am currently using to produce *those* results is this:

```
<li class="manage-files-list">
<div class="container">
<a class="right" target="_blank" href="">view</a>
<div class="left">
<a href="../reallylongfilelink.html"></a> 
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

And

```
li.manage-files-list {
width: 100%;
display: table;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.container{
border-bottom:1px solid white;
color:#666;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.left {
margin-right:70px;
word-break: break-all;
height:100%;
border-right:1px solid #fff;
}

.right {
width: 70px;
float: right;
text-align: center;
background-color:#333;
display:inline-table !important;
vertical-align: middle;
height:100%;
}
```

The only other requirement I can think of is that it needs to be wrapped in an `<li>` tag, but I don't see why that would be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you are okay using `display: table*;` values, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtZsb/) showing a solution using that.

It sets both `.left` and `.right` to display table cell, stops `float`ing `.right` and instead moves it to be the second element. The issue was that your floating was causing the browser to ignore the `height` and the `display` property and just treat it as a floated block.

Also, making sure you are aware, these solutions using `display: table*;` are [compatible IE8+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

Comment: Boy do I dislike `display: table` though.

Comment: @Wex I agree, but until we get browsers with full CSS `column` support, it is sometimes the best option we've got. Once I can just start doing `columns: 2;`, I will be so happy.

Comment: The problem with this solution though is that the right column is not being pushed to the right. You can see this happen in your fiddle if you put `font-size:4px;` on the `li` tag..

Comment: [IE, how you always seem to fall behind on the standards...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

Comment: @Charlie Set the `width` on the `.left` column to be `100%` and it should fix the problem. It's a trick with table cells to get one to take up all the space.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't really recommend using `.left` and `.right` as class names, the solution really only requires you to set `overflow: hidden` and `word-wrap: break-word` for your `.left` `<div>`.

```
.right { float: right; }
.left { 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/HzpJu/

Comment: I only had the class names set to those names because I was testing just this one issue. I don't keep them like that.

Comment: Any reason why you went with `display: table` instead of my answer?

Comment: I wanted the height of the columns to be 100%, but I wanted the container to retain it's `auto` height. It seemed that using `display:table` worked for that...

Comment: You can achieve cross-browser compatible, equal heights columns using things like [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). Just an FYI